# Can you conditionally pass a variable to Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

So I am building a component and want the ability to bind a value to it or leave it blank. Ideally I would like to do this without the if statement maybe with filters or some type of ternary operator. So can I ever use this without explicitly passing a `date`

```
{% if date is not defined %}
    <input type='text' name="date" value="" class="form-control date-picker" />
    <input type='hidden' name="timezone" class="timezone" />
{% else %}
    <input type='text' name="{{date.name | default("date")}}" value="{{ date.value | default("")}}" class="form-control date-picker" />
    <input type='hidden' name="timezone" class="timezone" />
{% endif %}
```

This is the ugly broken code I ended up with after trying multiple things.

I cannot load the component without giving it a value for `date`

```
$date = '';
return $this->render('ComponentBundle:Default:datepicker.html.twig',array(
            'date' => $date,
       ));
```

The error i get when i don't pass `date` to the view is

```
Variable "date" does not exist in ComponentBundle:Default:datepicker.html.twig at line 10
```

Comment: @ErenArdahan I am new to php and symfony but i dont see how i am using session? I just wanna have null undefined checks in my view. Is that possible?

Comment: I know you are not using sessions..I also dont use symfony..I used the try twig as a package..And some reasons i stopped using it..One of the reason was that it doesn't support sessions..And it seems like there is a error because you are passing an array and u try to reach that array like a variable..

Comment: @ErenArdahan so you suggest making them all there own variables?

Comment: @jacknocke: have you tried `{%if date is empty %}` in conjunction with defining an empty date?

Comment: The way you use the `default()` filter is right - `{{date.name | default("date")}}` works if `date` and/or `date.name` isn't defined. Additionally, your template should also work if you don't pass the `date` variable from the controller to the template. I guess the error is somewhere else. Are you using the `date` variable somewhere else in your template, without `default()` filter? Can you give us a bit more context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot conditionally pass a variable but you can set and test some variables inside twig. example :

```
{% set var_date = date is defined and date is not empty ? date : {'name': 'date', 'value': ''} %}

<input type='text' name="{{ var_date.name }}" value="{{ var_date.value }}" class="form-control date-picker" />
<input type='hidden' name="timezone" class="timezone" />
```